# A confused question about polar reference frame in uniform circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems

For a particle with circular motion, the position vector of the particle can be expressed in the form of polar coordinates as
$$\vec{r}=rcos\theta\hat{x}+rsin\theta\hat{y}$$
Thus, the velocity is
$$\dot{\vec{r}}=\dot{r}cos\theta\hat{x}-rsin\theta\dot{\theta}\hat{x}+\dot{r}sin\theta\hat{y}+rcos\theta\dot{\theta}\hat{y}$$
Since $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, we can obtain
$$\dot{r}=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\dot{x}+\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\dot{y}=\dot{x}cos\theta+\dot{y}sin\theta$$
Finally,
$$\dot{\vec{r}}=(\dot{x}cos\theta cos\theta+\dot{y}sin\theta cos\theta-y\dot{\theta})\hat{x}+(\dot{x}cos\theta sin\theta+\dot{y}sin\theta sin\theta+x\dot{\theta})\hat{y}$$
But, **in reality**,
$$\dot{\vec{r}}=(\dot{x}-y\dot{\theta})\hat{x}+(\dot{y}+x\dot{\theta})\hat{y}$$
What's wrong with this?

**EDIT:**

Original question: If a particle fixed on a rotating reference frame with angular velocity $\omega\hat{z}$, the velocity of the particle corresponds to the frame would be:
$$\dot{\vec{r}}=(\dot{x}-y\dot{\theta})\hat{x}+(\dot{y}+x\dot{\theta})\hat{y}+\dot{z}\hat{z}$$
My modification: If neglecting the motion along $z$, the question will actually become to a 2D question lies in $x-y$ plane. So, according to relativitic, I think we can make the rotating reference frame be static and let the particle rotate around $z$. Can this **Equivalent method** work? Or why not?

Comment: What you say should happen in reality is wrong as you can immediately see by writing $\vec{r} = x \hat{x}+y \hat{y}$. 

Its not even consistent with your second equation.

Comment: The eqution, $\dot{\vec{r}}=(\dot{x}-y\dot{\theta})\hat{x}+(\dot{y}+x\dot{\theta})\hat{y}$, is absolutly right.

Comment: R would be constant check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion#In_polar_coordinates

Comment: @Feynman: Where did you find the last equation in your post? Note also that e.g $\partial r/\partial x \neq \cos \theta$.

Comment: Wouldn't $\dot{r}=0$ for circular motion?

Comment: @user35122, the question added an edit.

Comment: @ CAF 1 , the question added an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Both $r$ and $\theta$ are $x$, $y$ dependence,

\begin{align*}
  \tan \theta &= \frac{y}{x} \\[4pt]
  \dot{\theta} \sec^2 \theta &= \frac{x\dot{y}-\dot{x} y}{x^2} \\[4pt]
  \frac{\dot{\theta} (x^2+y^2)}{x^2} &= \frac{x\dot{y}-\dot{x} y}{x^2} \\[4pt]
  r^2\dot{\theta} &= x\dot{y}-\dot{x} y \\[4pt]
  r\dot{\theta} &= \dot{y} \cos \theta-\dot{x} \sin \theta \\[4pt]
  \mathbf{v} &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{r} \cos \theta-r\dot{\theta} \sin \theta \\
    \dot{r} \sin \theta+r\dot{\theta} \cos \theta
  \end{bmatrix} \\[4pt]
  &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    (\dot x \cos \theta+\dot y \sin \theta) \cos \theta-
    (\dot y \cos \theta-\dot x \sin \theta) \sin \theta \\
    (\dot x \cos \theta+\dot y \sin \theta) \sin \theta+
    (\dot y \cos \theta-\dot x \sin \theta) \cos \theta
  \end{bmatrix} \\[4pt] &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot x \\ \dot y
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

> **Updates:**
>
> $S$: Inertial frame
>
> $S'$: Rotating frame
>
> $$\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}'+\boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf{r}'$$

Comment: the question added an edit.

Comment: Answer updated.  You should use different denotations for rotating frame and inertial frame.